# Make ScrollView - Items use a percentage size of the whole screen

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, scrollview

My current scrollview items have the problem, that I need to set a fixed height and width for them in order to show up properly on different devices.

Every scrollview item should use 1/6 of the screen height in order to fit for different screen sizes... but how do we achieve this without making the scrollview unscrollable ?

My current attempt...

```
 <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}} contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}>

    { /* Renders the header */}
    <Header text={Constants.header} screen="Drills&Games"/>

     <BoxView></BoxView>
     <BoxView></BoxView>
     <BoxView></BoxView>
     <BoxView></BoxView>
     <BoxView></BoxView>

  </ScrollView>



export default class BoxView extends Component{

    render(){

        return(

            <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', flex: 0.25}}>

            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Renders a scrollview with 5 BoxView-Items... The problem here is... the box views do scale correctly, each one uses 0.25 flex, but the list is not scrollable anymore.

So how do we pass a percentage/flex height to the items with keeping the scrollview scrollable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On react native I recommend using [Dimensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions) on setting dynamic height.

for getting the 1/6 of the screen I would do is

```
{ height: Dimensions.get("screen").height * 0.16 }
```